# axis webservice java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, tomcat, axis

Currently i am facing an issue with axis 1.3 web services when migrated to tomcat 8 and JDK 8 from jdk 1.7 and tomcat 5.3 .

I never get this issue on my first call but on my second call to the same werservice i get the `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

When hitting the werservice url on my browser the WSDL opens up but when hitting the same url with soap UI i get the same error.

Kindly help ..........

Technology stack :- jdk 1.8
tomcat 8
axis 1.3

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Jens, There is no stack trace as such present my UI gives me this error when the response is returned from the Axis layer. Is this any kind of issue when i upgraded tomcat 7 to tomcat8?